# Free linked list containing structures containing structures

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, free, ls

This is for school.

I'm working on an implementation of the Unix 'ls' command. For this I'm using linked lists each time I'm reading a directory (so only one time if the -R option is not set). For this I have to use the linked lists functions and nodes (or elements, I'm not sure what's the correct name.) that we had to code on a previous project. Those nodes looks like this:

```
typedef struct s_list
{
    void          *content;
    size_t         content_size;
    struct s_list *next;
}t_list;
```

In my ls program, I use these to store, for each file in the directory I'm listing, it's name and it's stats, obtained with the stat() function. So the 'content' pointer of my t_list is this structure:

```
typedef struct s_entry
{
    char       *filename;
    struct stat filestat;
}t_entry;
```

Everything works fine, the only problem I got is that Valgrind tell me there's a leak comming from the malloc() used to allocate those t_entry structures. So I guess I'm freeing them up wrong.. here's how I do it:

```
void    free_list(t_list *entries)
{
    t_list *n_node;

    if (!entries)
        return ;
    while (entries)
    {
        n_node = entries->next;
        free(entries->content);
        free(entries);
        entries = n_node;
    }
}
```

I'm guessing it is not enough to just free the *content pointer, but I tried other ways and it wont works. If I try to free like

```
free(entries->content->filename);
```

for example, it doesn't works and the fact that the content is a void pointer seems to be a problem in some ways that I tried to resolve the problem, but that's the way we had to code those linked list functions.

If someone could give me an hint on how to free these lists correctly, It would be awesome as I'm really stuck on this. Thanks in advance.
Sorry if my english or explanation isn't clear enough.

ps: Just in case, the whole project (far from finished) can be found here:
    https://github.com/Zestx/ft_ls

Comment: For short-running programs like `ls`, it's often more efficient to not bother `free`ing memory because it's all returned to the OS at the end. But if you do want to, the issue seems to be casting: the compiler doesn't know that `entries->content` is a pointer to an `s_entry`, but you do, so you should cast it appropriately and then you can get at the `filename`.

Comment: What happens when you try to free filename? Void pointer wouldn't be a problem to free

Comment: Ohh yeah compiler can't directly access filename from void pointer but this hasn't to do about free

Comment: @geckos if I try it like this: free(entries->content->filename) I get this: util.c: In function ‘free_list’:
util.c:69:24: error: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [-Werror]
   free(entries->content->filename)
                        ^~
util.c:69:24: error: request for member ‘filename’ in something not a structure or union
util.c:69:35: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘free’

Comment: @DanielH sorry but I'm not sure how/where I should do this cast. And to be clear, The program does compile and works. There's just a leak!

Comment: Update: I do a copy of the node at somepoint without freeing the original. This is the reason it leaked, not the free_list function. Sorry for the noise!

Comment: It looks like your filenames point into `readdir` results. That should not leak, but it's also very fragile, as the results may be overwritten by another read on the same stream.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks for the review. I'll fix that!

Comment: try something like this `free(((t_entry *) entries->content)->filename)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your list of `ls` entries for each file within a directory where `content` is a pointer to an allocated `t_entry` containing the filename and `stat` information, e.g.

```
typedef struct s_list {
    void          *content;
    size_t         content_size;
    struct s_list *next;
} t_list;
```

and

```
typedef struct s_entry {
    char       *filename;
    struct stat filestat;
} t_entry;
```

A `freelist (t_list *head)` function would need to iterate over each node, and:

1. `free` the `filename` allocated within each `t_entry`;
2. `free` the allocated `t_entry`; and finally
3. `free` the `t_list` node itself.

You could do something similar to the following:

```
void freelist (t_list *head)
{
    t_list *node = head;        /* temporary node to iterate list  */
                                /* (you could use head, but don't) */
    while (*node) {
        t_list *victim = node;  /* pointer to current node to free */
        t_entry *entry = node->content;     /* pointer to content */

        free (entry->filename)  /* free content->filename */
        free (entry);           /* free t_entry struct itself */

        node = node->next;      /* advance before freeing victim */

        free (victim);          /* free current t_list node (victim) */
    }
}
```

Note above, instead of using `node`, you could simply use `head` to iterate since `freelist` receives a copy that would not alter the list address anyway -- and since there will be no list left when you are done, but it is a far better habit to use a temporary node to iterate the list (in any function) so you do not confuse the circumstances when you are handling the actual list address (e.g. the parameter was `t_list **`) or a copy of the pointer (the parameter was `t_list *`).

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast data so that the compiler knows where to find struct members, here is a full example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct s_list
{
    void          *content;
    size_t         content_size;
    struct s_list *next;
}t_list;

typedef struct s_entry
{
    char       *filename;
    struct stat filestat;
}t_entry;

int main(void)
{
    t_list *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);
    t_entry *bar = malloc(sizeof *bar);
    bar->filename = malloc(10);
    foo->content = bar;

    free(((t_entry *)foo->content)->filename);
    free(foo->content);
    free(foo);

    return 0;
}
```